# access and filter explicit NA values created by parse_factor()

Tags: r, missing-data, readr

`readr::parse_factor()` is the tidyverse way to create factor variables. By default, it sets `include_na = TRUE`: an explicit NA level will be created for NA values in the vector that is passed to `parse_factor()`. After a factor variable has been created with `parse_factor()`, how can one access or filter these "explicit NA" values?

This code illustrates the issue:

```
library(readr)
xFac <- parse_factor(c("a", "b", NA))
levels(xFac)        # NA is a level of xFac
is.na(xFac)         # FALSE FALSE FALSE
xFac == "NA"        # FALSE FALSE FALSE
xFac[!is.na(xFac)]  # a    b    <NA>
```

In the last line, I try to get only those values of `xFac` that aren't NA. But the line doesn't work; the NA value is returned along with the others. What is the right way to write this line (while keeping the explicit NA values in `xFac`)?

A number of SO posts ask how to filter ordinary NA values. Those posts don't seem relevant here: my question is about the "explicit NA" values that are created by `parse_factor()`, and by design, they don't behave in the same way as ordinary NA values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it into a character vector and then use `is.na()`.

```
> xFac
[1] a    b    <NA>
Levels: a b <NA>

> xFac[!is.na(as.character(xFac))]
[1] a b
Levels: a b <NA>
```

Or you can use `%in%`

```
> xFac[!xFac %in% NA]
[1] a b
Levels: a b <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you. The second solution, involving `%in%`, is appealing because it is so succinct.

Answer (score 1):

A factor is actually an integer vector whose value indicates which of the levels it corresponds to.

So, if you look at the levels:

```
levels(xFac)
#> [1] "a" "b" NA 
is.na(levels(xFac))
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

The level is actually `NA`. So, you just need to find the elements of `xFac` whose levels are `NA`, i.e. whose integer value is `3`.

```
as.integer(xFac) == which(is.na(levels(xFac)))
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

And you can put that in a function:

```
is_na_factor <- function(x){
  as.integer(x) == which(is.na(levels(x)))
}
xFac[! is_na_factor(xFac)]
#> [1] a b
#> Levels: a b <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
#Code 1
xFac <- parse_factor(c("a", "b", NA),include_na = F,na=c('NA'))
#Code 2
xFac[!is.na(xFac)]
```

Output:

```
xFac[!is.na(xFac)]
[1] a b
Levels: a b
```

Also:

```
xFac
[1] a    b    <NA>
Levels: a b
```

Comment: Thank you. But my hope is to find a way to deal with the "explicit NA" level that `parse_factor()` creates by default when it encounters NA values.